# How can I extract out lines that contains "g__" at their end?

Tags: command-line, text-processing

I want to extract the lines that end with `g__something`. In the following example some lines contain `g__something` followed by `s__something`. I don't want to extract them. I want only those lines that end with `g__something`.

[image: here is the text]

Only three lines in this example should be extracted, those that have `g__Bifidobacterium`, `g__Aeriscardovia` and `g__Aeriscardovia` at their end.

How can I do that?

Comment: For many good reasons, [please don't post images of text](http://meta.unix.stackexchange.com/questions/4086/psa-please-dont-post-images-of-text?cb=1)

Comment: Yes. Every time I tried to paste my text as preformatted text, it fails to paste. Rather, an image link pops out forcing to post the text as image only.

Comment: You should be able to copy and paste the text from a text file and then apply code formatting to it here. I would love to try answering your question, but I don't want to type all that, and I am failing to get an accurate version with OCR.

Answer (score 1):

Using the standard shell letter ranges will work mostly, but use the `LC_COLLATE=C` to be on the safe side.  Bash's range implementation follows the docs, but may produce unexpected results for non-C locales.

```
LC_COLLATE=C
grep g__[a-zA-Z]*$ yourfile
```

---

You missed the "$", which is the symbol for the "end of line".  Without that $, of course, the string matches anywhere on the line.

---

Since nothing still matches, likely there is some non-printing character at the end of the line, like a space, tab, carriagereturn,...  Cannot tell from the picture posted, so simply add what's really at the end of the line before the "$", or try something like (for one or more spaces):

```
grep "g__[a-zA-Z]*[ ]*$"
```

Note the added quotes around the string.  Adding more possible non-printing characters is left as an exercise for the reader (easier in a script to add these odd characters), but there are character classes for this, e.g.

```
[^[:print:][:blank:]]
```

Comment: command `grep "g__[a-zA-Z]*" merged_abundance.txt > abc.txt` takes those lines which has only "g__" in it. Even those have "g_[a-zA-Z]|s__[a-zA-Z]". I don't need these. I only need lines end with "g__[a-zA-Z]".  Thanks

Comment: `grep g__[a-zA-Z]*$ merged_abundance.txt > abc.tsv` it results into an empty file

Comment: Sorry. I put the question wrong. I am going to put a new question.